# Pandas return value of column with conditional row statemnet on a different column

Tags: python, pandas

What is an equivalent of the following:

```
import pandas as pd 
x=pd.DataFrame([['a','a','b','c'],[1,2,3,4]],columns=['lets','nums'])
b_nums=x[x['lets']=='b'].loc['nums']
```

Should return 3
I can do

```
y=x[x['lets']=='b']
b_nums=y.loc['nums']
```

The values I'm searching for are unique however there's got to be a more efficient way

Comment: What do you mean more efficient what specifically are you trying to optimize? `b_nums = x.loc[x['lets']=='b', 'nums']` avoids a copy and subsequent lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single condition:

```
x[x.lets=='b'].nums.values
```

For any of multiple conditions:

```
x[x.lets.isin(["b", "c"])].nums.values
```